# Gridview inside a ModalPopUpExtender causes ModalPopUpExtender to close

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, ajax

I have a gridview inside a ModalPopUpExtender, the grid view have the button add delete and edit when i clic one of the button of the gridview the popup is closed. I wont to close the popup when  the close button is clicked.
This is the asp.net part:

```
< cc1: ModalPopupExtender ID="NamePopup" runat="server" PopupControlID="OptionPanel" TargetControlID="btnD"  BackgroundCssClass="mpBg" DropShadow="true" OkControlID="btnSavePopup" CancelControlID="btnPostCancel" >
    < / cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click is triggering a Page Load, even though you're using the Ajax Controls.

Look at the last post [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1450434.aspx) for one person's solution.  Use google if that won't work for you.

Comment: I solve this problem this case, this is the solution:
I insert the gridview inside a ajax update panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your popup panel to persist by calling `ModalPopupExtender.Show()` method from inside the server-side methods that handle postbacks from controls inside your popup panel.